# Memory corruption after running malloc

Tags: c, pointers, memory-corruption

I am writing a pet project (a sort of single-threaded Lisp-like language interpreter in C), and I came upon the following issue: a pointer is overwritten while `malloc()` is run. Showing all the code would be too long, but I can share it if necessary. I would like to have some insight regarding how the problem can be debugged.

The bug happens during the subroutine that runs a user-defined function:

```
/* Determine the amount of arguments to the called function */
int argc = ast_len(fn_args)
printf("%s:%d %p\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, (void*) scope->vars->tail);
/* Allocate the memory to store the array of pointers to each of the arguments */
struct YL_Var** argv = malloc(sizeof(struct YL_Var*)*argc);
printf("%s:%d %p\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, (void*) scope->vars->tail);
```

You will get the following output:

```
interpreter.c:549 0x5558371c9480
interpreter.c:551 0x411
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The pointer `scope->vars->tail` is overwritten during the call to `malloc()`!

Using gdb and hardware break points clearly showed that the value was overwritten inside malloc.c.

[image: Assembly in GDB]
[image: HW breakpoint in GDB]

As the pointer is overwritten, the program segfaults soon after, both within gdb and in normal run. However it does not segfault when run inside valgrind, it even ends successfully.
So here is my question. How would you start to debug this mess? I am asking for advice, and not for an answer.
I am far from being a C expert :)

I guess I am at fault and this is of course no bug in glibc-2.26 or gcc 7.2.0.

- I have no warnings on gcc with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`
- valgrind shows some unfreed memory issue. Will fix them before doing anything else.

Comment: Where does `scope` point? Where does `scope->vars` point? Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: GCC on linux has flags for detecting out of bounds access. Try those.

Comment: By the way, the output you show doesn't match the code. If the first output comes from line 549, then there's a comment on line 550, followed by the `malloc` call on line 551 (which the second line in the output claims it comes from). *Then* the second `printf` happens on line 552. We really need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Oh and you should probably be using e.g. [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to help you find memory problems.

Comment: Do you get **any** reports from Valgrind? Also try gcc sanitizers, esp. address and UB.

Comment: It's almost certainly not that "_a pointer is overwritten while `malloc()` is run_" but that either (**a**) a block of memory you are still trying to use (e.g. `scope->vars->tail`) has already been freed (or not properly allocated), or (**b**) something has written past the end of an allocated block and corrupted the internal structures used by `malloc()` etc.

Comment: This can only mean that any of the three elements of `scope->vars->tail` is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will go on researching.

@Some programmer dude
The gdb session was run without the comments and the printf's. Sorry for the confusion. While debugging, I will probably need to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Will post it if I succeed into making one.

Comment: @n.m.
valgrind reports some unfreed memory. I will look more into it and try the gcc sanitizers.

Comment: @TripeHound Thanks! These are possibilities I did not think about.

Comment: The problem with memory errors is they are almost _never_ detected at the point of error; it's often much later when you're doing a completely unrelated `malloc()` or `free()` that the run-time notices things are not as they should be. A common source of confusion with memory problems is that adding `printf()`s to try and trace things keeps moving the point-of-crash – because `printf()` very often involves a memory allocation, so adding them changes when the problem is first noticed!

Comment: Thanks. I will use valgrind to get rid of all my memory errors. Then I will see if the bug still happens!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone's comment, I found the issue.

`scope->vars` was not appropriately allocated (as some said).
When using `valgrind`, I found the following message:

```
==23054== Invalid write of size 8
==23054==    at 0x10A380: varlist_prepend (interpreter.c:277)
==23054==    by 0x109548: main (yl.c:39)
==23054==  Address 0x5572a98 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==23054==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23054==    by 0x10A304: varlist_prepend (interpreter.c:274)
==23054==    by 0x109548: main (yl.c:39)
==23054==
```

My code looked like this:

```
struct YL_VarList* vars = malloc(sizeof(vars));
```

As you can see, the `*` was missing.
This is the corrected version:

```
struct YL_VarList* vars = malloc(sizeof(*vars));
```

`sizeof(vars)` would return the size of `struct YL_VarList*`, while I want to allocate the size of `struct YL_VarList`.